# HAProxy: Redirect Root Site Root to Subsite

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I would like to redirect the root of my website to a subsite by default. Like

```
http://www.domain.com/ ---> http://www.domain.com/subsite
```

I have tried this, but this matches all the URLs anyway:

```
acl is_root path_beg -i /
acl is_domain hdr(host) -i www.domain.com

redirect code 301 location http://www.domain.com/subsite if is_domain is_root
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

nlu is almost there, but the `is_root` ACL is a little bit off.

Using `path_beg` will lead to any and all paths being matched, when really you only want to redirect requests with an empty path.

Try using `acl is_root path -i /` instead since it will only match when the path is ONLY /.

```
acl is_root path -i /
acl is_domain hdr(host) -i www.domain.com

redirect code 301 location http://www.domain.com/subsite if is_domain is_root
```

Comment: No problem, I find keeping track of all the derivatives of the sampling keywords to get a little bewildering myself, never mind keeping track of the keywords themselves.

Comment: In my use case, a match is also made for /?someurl. Meaning, it will follow the redirect, which is undesired.

Comment: It’s matching ‘/?someurl’  using the `path` sampler?

Comment: I only want the root path to be redirected, meaning domain.com/ So, I use the code you supplied. When configured, I also get redirected when using /another_url, which is undesired.

Comment: But are you using the `path`, or `path_beg` sampler?

Comment: i am using `path`

Answer (score 1):

You can check, if it already starts with subsite and use the negated condition in the redirect:

```
acl is_subdomain    path_reg    ^/subsite/


acl is_root path_beg -i /
acl is_domain hdr(host) -i www.domain.com

redirect code 301 location http://www.domain.com/subsite if is_domain ! is_subdomain
```

Comment: This won't work. I would like to redirect `/` to `/subsite`...

Comment: Hope I got it right now

Comment: This would work only for this subsite, however, it would be a maintenance burden as we add new subsites. Greg's solution is exactly what I needed. Thanks for helping, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, then i use acl below to resolved my issue.

```
    acl is_root path_beg -i /
    http-request set-path /subsite if is_root
```